# How to open new window on center of screen on Lubuntu

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, window

I am currently facing a slight problem with Lubuntu.

When I open a new window, it is placed on the top left. I find this annoying because I moved my panel to the top, and therefore the window border looks the same as the panel.

How do I make it launch on the center?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the configuration file with text editor, I'll use leafpad as it was the default editor.

```
leafpad $HOME/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

Scroll to the last line, search for `</applications>` tag, located before. Once you found it, paste following to line **before** `</applications>` tag:

```
<application type="normal">
  <position>
    <x>center</x>
    <y>center</y>
  </position>
</application>
```

Finally, apply new configuration by reconfiguring openbox:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

Try opening program, notice now they now pop up on the center of screen.